# laravel get microtime from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, microtime

In a MySQL database I have a datetime field stored like this:

`2015-05-12 13:58:25.000508`

But when I execute this query, for example:

```
    $query = SdkEvent::with('sdkEventStack');

            if (isset($params['CO_ID']) && $params['CO_ID'] != "") {
                $query->where('CO_ID', $params['CO_ID']);
            }

            if (isset($params['APP_ID']) && $params['APP_ID'] != "") {
                $query->where('APP_ID', $params['APP_ID']);
            }

            if (isset($params['app_ip']) && $params['app_ip'] != "") {
                $query->where('SDKEVENT_IP', 'LIKE', $params['app_ip'].'%');
            }

            if (isset($params['PLACE_ID']) && $params['PLACE_ID'] != "") {
                $query->where('PLACEMENT_ID', $params['PLACE_ID']);
            }

    $sdks = $query->get();
```

I get the datetime like this: `2015-05-12 13:58:25`
Why am I not getting the microseconds ?

Comment: What type of datetype do you have it stored as in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an issue with Laravel, it is an issue with PDO, which Laravel uses for making database queries.

For more info see this other question: [PHP How to return datetime(6) from Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026570/php-how-to-return-datetime6-from-mysql)

or the actual bug report

http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/11524dvh68/php-bug-bug-54648-new-pdo-forces-format-of-datetime-fields

You can pull microseconds by using a `DB::select()` statement. For example:

```
$test = DB::select("SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%f') as date FROM test");
```