# Laravel timestamps to show milliseconds

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to store updated_at timestamp with high precision on a laravel application, using the format **"m-d-Y H:i:s.u"** (including milisseconds)

According to laravel documentation, I can customize the date format by setting the $dateFormat property on a class, but...

The main problem is that Laravel's schema builder adds a column of type timestamp in the database when I use **$table->nullableTimestamps()** And according to mysql documentation, columns of type TIMESTAMP only allow the precision up to seconds..

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried with mutators ? Something like [this](http://laravel.io/forum/04-27-2014-add-milliseconds-to-eloquents-created-atupdated-at?page=1)

Answer (score 17):

You can't because the PHP PDO driver doesn't support fractional seconds in timestamps. A work around is to select the timestamp as a string instead so the PDO driver doesn't know its really a timestamp, simply by doing `$query->selectRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(my_date_column) as my_date_column"))` however this means you can't use the default select for all fields so querying becomes a real pain. Also you need to override getDateFormat on the model.

```
// override to include micro seconds when dates are put into mysql.
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
}
```

Finally in your migration rather than nullableTimestamps, outside of the Schema callback do:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$tableName` ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP(3) NULL");
```

Note this example was for 3 decimal places however you can have up to 6 if you like, by changing the 3 to a 6 in two places, in the alter table and in the sprintf and also adjusting the multiplier * 1000 to 1000000 for 6.

Hopefully some day PHP PDO will be updated to fix this, but its been over 5 years and nothings changed so I don't have my hopes up. In case you are interested in the details, see this bug report:
http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/11524dvh68/php-bug-bug-54648-new-pdo-forces-format-of-datetime-fields
I found that link in this other answer which might help you more understand the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22990991/259521

PHP is really showing its age lately, and I would consider this issue one of my reasons for considering moving to the more modern Node.js.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [malhal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930762/539149), I was able to get fractional timestamp reading to work [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3506#issuecomment-294208300).  Pasting the answer here for convenience:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u';

    protected function asDateTime($value)
    {
        try {
            return parent::asDateTime($value);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return parent::asDateTime(new \DateTimeImmutable($value));
        }
    }

    public function newQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::newQuery();

        if($this->usesTimestamps()) {
            $table = $this->getTable();
            $column = $this->getDeletedAtColumn();

            $query->addSelect(DB::raw("concat($table.$column) as $column"));
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

There is a lot going on here because it gets the query with scopes applied and then adds a select for the updated_at column to the end, which overwrites any previously loaded updated_at column later while Laravel hydrates the Model from the query. For being an ugly hack, it worked surprisingly well the very first time.

Timestamps are stored internally as [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) in Laravel:

```
dd(MyModel->first()->updated_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'));
```

Output:

```
2017-04-14 22:37:47.426131
```

Also be sure to run a migration to convert your columns to fractional timestamps. Microsecond precision raises the size of timestamps from 4 bytes to 7 bytes but this is 2017, don't let saving a byte or two by choosing millisecond precision cost you a fortune later when you find yourself serving stale cache entries:

```
\DB::statement("ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY updated_at TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL");
```

Sadly I haven't found a way to modify the migration schema `timestamps()` function to do this.

Comment: When using your newQuery function I dont get the full object returned to me after adding the selects.  I feel like something is missing here as far as querying goes

Answer (score 0):

Support for fractional seconds was added in Laravel 7 (3/2020). Here's an example where we assume we want microsecond precision for `created_at`, `updated_at` and `banned_at` on a hypothetical User model:

In the up() method of your migration:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // other columns
        $table->timestamp('created_at', 6);
        $table->timestamp('updated_at', 6);
        $table->timestamp('banned_at', 6)->nullable();
    });
}
```

Then in the User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
    protected $casts = [
        'banned_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.u',
    ];
}
```

If you have an existing timestamp you need to change, you can create a migration and do the following:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamp('banned_at', 6)->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

Usage:

```
dd(User::first(1)->banned_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'));
```

Output:

```
"2023-12-02 06:52:46.549267"
```