# Laravel not retrieving milliseconds in DateTime columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In Laravel, I have some columns with milliseconds. Note that some other columns do not have milliseconds (e.g. `created_at`, `updated_at`).

Here is my migration:

```
Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->dateTime('sync_date_time', 3);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My model is simply:

```
class Brand extends Model {}
```

Yet when I have a record with milliseconds (e.g. `2018-12-19 01:40:46.512`) , and execute:

```
$brand->sync_date_time;
```

It always returns a string without the milliseconds portion (e.g. `2018-12-19 01:40:46`).

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this issue?

Note that this is not a Carbon issue, as I am not using Carbon for this field at all.

I saw a similar question here:

[Laravel timestamps to show milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227069/laravel-timestamps-to-show-milliseconds)

that claims this is in fact a PDO issue and suggest using a string or timestamp. But it's quite an old answer, so I was hoping there is a better answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel timestamps to show milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227069/laravel-timestamps-to-show-milliseconds)

Comment: just writing @cfnerd 's answer. format("m-d-Y H:i:s.u") must work.

Comment: @cfnerd Firstly I haven't even introduced Carbon into this. So the `format` method is not available. But even if I add dateTime in the `casts` property, that just returns the milliseconds as 0.

Comment: It's not that I can't use Carbon. The returned attribute is a string. I haven't even casted it to any other type. So casting the string `2018-12-19 01:40:46` to  DateTime, and then formatting it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with Laravel, but due to a known bug in PDO with newer versions of MySQL.

This issue exists in PHP 7.2 and has been fixed in PHP 7.3.

So to fix this issue, just upgrade to **PHP 7.3**.

If you want to auto-cast to a Carbon date, I found the following does NOT work when it comes to `setting`, `saving` and `toArray`:

```
protected $casts = [
   'sync_date_time' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.v',
];
```

Instead I found that you must have nothing in casts for the column, and add the following methods to the model:

```
public function getSyncDateTimeAttribute(string $value): Carbon
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.v', $value);
}

public function setSyncDateTimeAttribute(Carbon $value): void
{
    $this->attributes['fidel_created'] = $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.v');
}
```

But remember you still need to upgrade to PHP 7.3!

Comment: please fix the second method name (set...). thanks

Comment: @mwallisch done. Good spot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug with Lumen 8.

I've change  this code in my model class :

```
protected $casts = [
    'last_activity_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

to

```php
    public function getLastActivityAtAttribute(?string $value): ?Carbon
    {
        return empty($value) ? null : Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.v', $value);
    }

    public function setLastActivityAtAttribute(Carbon $value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['last_activity_at'] = $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.v');
    }
```

Milliseconds save well now.

I tried this code too but it doesn't work :

```
protected $casts = [
    'last_activity_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s.v',
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the top of your model:

`protected $dates = ['sync_date_time'];`

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) will automatically cast this to a Carbon instance which you can then format simply with:

`$brand->sync_date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')`

You can also try setting the protected `$dateFormat` variable at the top of your model too.

Comment: Tried that but the milliseconds just shows up as zeros

Comment: And they're definitely 100% not zeros in the database correct? Since they'll be defaulted if not provided when saved.

Comment: 100% not zero's in DB. Try it your self with any new version of MySQL. It looks like a known issue.

Comment: Could you go in to mysql and run a query to select that record with the datetime? Something like `select sync_date_time from table where x = y` and does it show the microseconds?

Comment: Yes. The issue can be fixed by upgrading to PHP 7.3. This is a bug in PDO.