# Laravel Carbon not saving milliseconds

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `timestamp(6)` column in my database called `date`. When I use the `Model::insert()` method to insert to the database - bypassing Eloquent and using Laravel QueryBuilder, the timestamp precision is lost.

Eg. if I pass '2023-01-24T02:02:02.222222Z' to the `date` column:

```
Item::insert(['date' => Carbon\Carbon::parse('2023-01-24T02:02:02.222222Z')]);
```

I will have a timestamp which is saved as '2023-01-24T02:02:02.000000Z' in the database. The timestamp milliseconds is all zeros.

I can apply a format to convert the Carbon object to a string before saving. This works - but I am looking to apply this to every instance in my project so it is not ideal.

The `__toString` Carbon method formats a datetime to seconds precision. If I can change this default then this can be applied globally, but the only method I can find to do this is deprecated: `setToStringFormat`.

If I was globally able to set the `DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';` const in `CarbonInterface.php` to include milliseconds like `DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';` this might work. I'd like Carbon to always save milliseconds for all datetimes in my project.

How can I achieve this?

MySQL version is 5.7.37
Laravel version is 8.83.23

PHP version is 8.1

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted please?

Comment: @war10ck This is the insert statement I am executing: `Item::insert(['date' => Carbon\Carbon::parse('2023-01-24T02:02:02.222222Z')]);`. I can get this statement to save with timestamp precision by formatting to string. I'm looking for a global setting though.

Comment: @Arleigh Hix MySQL version is 5.7.37. I'm able to get millisecond precision in MySQL if I manually set the string before insert, but not through Carbon.

Comment: Laravel version?

Comment: @Arleigh Hix Laravel version is 8.83.23

Comment: Have you set the `$dateFormat` property on your model?

Comment: @ArleighHix yes it is set but should not matter here because we are bypassing the model using bulk insert.

Comment: The question is very unclear, specifically what you've tried and what happens.  Can you edit and show all the various different approaches you've tried, and the results?  Searching for "*laravel milliseconds*" turns up some answers here already, have you reviewed those?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227069/6089612,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54423856/6089612, ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic The question states the input, output and what is expected. These links refer to PHP 7.2 which I am not using (Laravel 8 minimum version is 7.3) and also updating through the model, as stated in the question - I am doing a bulk insert which does not use the Laravel model.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon [recommends](https://carbon.nesbot.com/laravel/#time-precision) set precision globally overriding the `getDateFormat()` function of the `MySqlGrammar` class:

```php
namespace App\Database\Query\Grammars;

class MySqlGrammar extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar
{
    public function getDateFormat()
    {
        return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
    }
}
```

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        \DB::connection()->setQueryGrammar(new \App\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar);
    }
```

This won't change the `__toString()` Carbon method, but will force Laravel to store microseconds in the database even Eloquent is not used.