# Store date and time with milliseconds in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want my timestamp column to store milliseconds as well.
When the date is saved in my column, it shows the date and time correctly but the milliseconds are just 000000.

```
$table->timestamp('date_time', 6);
```

Above is the change that I made to my migration file to store the milliseconds.
How can I make it so that when storing date time, the milliseconds are stored automactially or do I have to store it manually and if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel timestamps to show milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227069/laravel-timestamps-to-show-milliseconds)

Comment: Which database?

Comment: WHY to use PHP to record date time stamp this function is itself available in every database on creation of record or updation of record kindly search that it would be more easy to record. If you want to display use date function of php

Comment: @b126 No it doesn't. The post is for a much older version of Laravel. The issue I'm facing shouldn't be a thing in Laravel 10 which is the version I'm using.

Comment: @HamidHosseini the way you migrate the table is correct, but we need to check where you get the time what happend and wich version of mysql you have, you need to be at MySQL version 5.6.4 or later to declare columns with fractional-second time.
To get milliecond you can olso try to get it using php native function 'microtime()'